# Print method question Python

Tags: python, string

In python, what does the 2nd % signifies?

```
print "%s" % ( i )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, this is the Python string formatting/interpolation operator.  It's basically the equivalent of sprintf in C, for example:

`a = "%d bottles of %s on the wall" % (10, "beer")`

is equivalent to something like

`a = sprintf("%d bottles of %s on the wall", 10, "beer");`

in C.  Each of these has the result of `a` being set to `"10 bottles of beer on the wall"`

Note however that this syntax is deprecated in Python 3.0; its replacement looks something like

`a = "{0} bottles of {1} on the wall".format(10, "beer")`

This works because any string literal is automatically turned into a str object by Python.

Answer (score 5):

The second % is the string interpolation operator.

[Link to documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 0):

It's a [format specifier](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Simple usage:

```
# Prints: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
for i in range(10):
    print "%d" % i,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "%d%s" % (100, "trillion dollars") # outputs: 100 trillion dollars
```

Comment: Actually, it outputs "100trillion dollars" — you're missing a space. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to translate the code to English, it says: take the ***string* i** and format it in to the predicate string.

Another example:

```
name = "world"
print "hello, %s" % (name)
```

[More information about format specifiers.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)